# url rewrite using subdomain returns "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I must be missing something very obvious here.  I'm trying to forward users who go to a subdomain like product1.mywebsite.com to go to www.mywebsite.com/products/?p=product1 where 'product1' is the variable I'm passing to the page.

I've read various posts on this site and others showing how easy it is but it JUST WON'T WORK!!!
I'm using ‪CentOS 6.10 with Plesk if that helps

Here's my latest attempt:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/pruducts/?p=$1 [L,R=301]
```

It's just like all the posts I've read but I'm missing something.  The .htaccess file is in the root folder of the website.  I've even tried putting it in the folder above it but still no joy.

It's like the site is looking for the subdomain and not finding it (because it doesn't exist) when it should just take the word used in the subdomain (in this case product1) and use it as a variable on the mywebsite.com/pruducts/ page.

Do I need to switch something on in Plesk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You condition *explicitly* states that the following rule should only get applied if the hostname has *nothing* before "mywebsite.com"...

A second issue with your approach is that you cannot access the hostname itself in a rewriting rule like you apparently try to.

---

Instead try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mywebsite.com/pruducts/?p=%1 [R=301]
```

---

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  Sadly that didn't work, I get the same error message.  Yuck!  I will put this in the host configuration when it works :)

Comment: @GeneralTomfoolery Please put a definite syntax error into that dynamic configuration file and try again. Still the same result in the browser? Then your issue is not the rewriting but either your network topology/name resolution or that such dynamic configuration files are not interpreted at all on your system.

Comment: Good thinking.  I took out a \ and it caused an error on the site BUT not when I tested the subdomain.  I'll contact support.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I added an A record to the DNS which was *.mydomain.com which sorted the "site can't be reached" error